# how to create textbox selected event with asp.net - c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, textbox

I was wondering how i can trigger an event when a textbox is selected or focused.
My textbox is an asp.net type.

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TB" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

When the event is triggered, i would like to do something in code-behind with c#.

thanks in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oki, so i figured it out by reading on an article on a different page.

check link: http://codingresource.blogspot.no/2010/01/how-to-use-events-like-onblur-onfocus.html

instead of using onblur i use onclick

Answer (score 2):

We do not have any textbox selected event in asp.net. You can try using text changed event of textbox or you can try using java script as below.

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function RefreshUpdatePanel() {
    __doPostBack('<%= Code.ClientID %>', '');
};
</script>

         <asp:TextBox ID="Code" runat="server" onkeyup="RefreshUpdatePanel();"     AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="Code_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="Update" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DateList" />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="CurrentTime" ></asp:TextBox>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Code" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Code behind : 

protected void Code_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Adding current time (minutes and seconds) into dropdownlist
        DateList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(DateTime.Now.ToString("mm:ss")));

        //Setting current time (minutes and seconds) into textbox
        CurrentTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("mm:ss");
    }

Comment: thanks for your help, but i figured out by a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Their is no serverside onfocus event for asp textbox you can use textchanged event as follows.using update panel of ajax control you can avoid page refreshment.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged1" ></asp:TextBox>

protected void TextBox1_TextChanged2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

On Client side onfocus event You can invoke a c# webmethord through ajax call as follows

HTML SOURCE

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#TextBox1").focus(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Default.aspx/test",
                        data: "{}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(msg) {
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
  </script>
```

C# code

```
   [WebMethod]
    public static void test()
    {

    }
```

Comment: interesting, but the client don't want to use ajax for the solution. I might try this on my next project. Thanks for your answer